# MVC Client validation rules not output when model property is excluded from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I am performing custom validation on a model property. The property is a proxy for other parts of the model and therefore requires no explicit user input. Server-side validation is working correctly but no client-side rules are generated.

I have been able to successfully generate the client rules but only when 'referencing the property in the view' using `TextBoxFor`, `CheckBoxFor` (or perhaps more appropriately `HiddenFor`) on the target property. However this feels like a hack, since the property doesn't even have a setter, so the value is guaranteed to be discarded.

Is there any way to force ASP.NET MVC to generate the client validation rules for a specific property without it being used in the view?

**Example Code**

```
public class Model {
    public bool Option1 { get; set; }
    public bool Option2 { get; set; }
    public bool Option3 { get; set; }

    [CustomValidator(ErrorMessage = "Validation Failed!")]
    public bool AtLeastOneSelected => Option1 != false || Option2 != false || Option3 != false;
}

public class CustomValidator : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable {
    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context) {
        // breakpoint below
        return new List<ModelClientValidationRule>();
    }
}
```

**Example View**

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Option1)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Option2)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Option3)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AtLeastOneSelected)

@*//Client rules will not be generated without this line*@
@*//@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AtLeastOneSelected)*@
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - you have a property that's not used, but you still want to validate? If it's not used in the view, how is it important to display it in the view? If it's a property that's derived from another property, that is used, why not put validation on that property instead?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen The example is over-simplified, in reality the proxy property represents several properties found in 'sub-models'. The validation must hang off something. As you suggest I could arbitrarily pick one of the 'real' properties in the sub-models but this validation is only relevant at the higher level of the composite model

Comment: But still - if the "final" property is dependant on user input - then that user input should be what's validated. Otherwise you give the user no way to know what to fix

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen the validation is context aware - by which I mean, it knows which fields are to be validated (these fields having user input) thereby making the proxy property value moot

Comment: Unclear what your expecting. The `TextBoxFor()` generates `data-val-*` attributes in the html it generates (based on the validation attributes) which in turn are read by `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` which in turn add the rules use by `jquery.validate`. If you dont include `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DerivedNumber)` then of course no rules will be added for that property

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen is absolutely right here. It's bad UX to present a validation error on a property the user has no ability to control directly. The fact that they can *indirectly* control it is meaningless, the context of the error gives them no map to do that. Validate the other properties, instead, to ensure that the composite of those will be valid as well. Then, you can present contextual errors the user can actually act on. If you can't do that because of the way the application is designed, *it's a bad design.*

Comment: @ChrisPratt I broadly agree with your points and in fact each individual item has it's own validation. There is a requirement to provide some additional validation messages when several complex models are combined on one screen. Perhaps the UI should be redesigned however that falls way outside the scope of the question.

Comment: @ChrisPratt when considering the re-worked example, which property should be decorated if `AtLeastOneSelected` is removed?

Comment: @RedTaz I've done this before I'm pretty sure; I'll have a look when I get home and I'll give you a shout if I find it

Comment: @RedTaz I found my code; I have done this before and there is no need for a hack; I'll try to get it all in shareable mode and post the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your sole problem here is that client-side validation doesn't work out of the box. This is because the validation client-side must be tied to a form field. There has to be something that triggers an valid/invalid determination, and without a form field you have nothing to do that with.

You can always write some custom client-side validation. Just check of your options and see if at least one is set, then you add/remove a message accordingly. You can check the jQuery Validation docs (what's behind client-side validation in MVC) for [`require_from_group`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method). Seems like pretty much what you want in this particular example. You'll just have to add the rule manually.

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    Option1: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".options"]
    },
    Option2: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".options"]
    },
    Option3: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".options"]
    }
  }
});
```

Then, you just need to add that class to each of your option fields.

Comment: Thanks, I've slept on it, now I understand why the premise of the question is flawed. When the client side is hooked up the contextual information has to be provided by the proxy element - so it *must* be included in the view

Comment: @RedTaz have you seen my answer? it doesn't have to be included in the form

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue to yours in that I had to validate three inputs in addition to their own validation due to some silly UI requirements.

I did manage to make it work with all the built-in stuff and without any need for a hack.

I needed a ValidationAttribute

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ValidationAttributes
{
    public sealed class MyValidationRule : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {
        public MyValidationRule()
            : base("My validation rule's error message {0}")
        {
            // initialise vars here
        }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            var valid = value == null;

            // validate logic here

            return valid;
        }

        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            yield return new ModelClientValidationMyValidationRule(FormatErrorMessage("SomeValueFor0ParamAbove"), MinimumAgeInYears);
        }
    }
}
```

... and a ModelClientValidationRule

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ModelClientValidationRules
{
    public class ModelClientValidationMyValidationRule : ModelClientValidationRule
    {
        public ModelClientValidationMyValidationRule(string errorMessage)
        {
            ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
            ValidationType = "myvalidatorrule";

            // add any params needed on the client side from the server side by using the following
            ValidationParameters.Add("param_name", "param_value");
        }
    }
}
```

... and I needed to add a prop in my Model

```
[MyValidationRule]
public whatever SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

... and I needed to add the client side validation in the view

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SomeProperty, "Validation message")
```

... and finally I needed to include some js in my scripts

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("myvalidationrule", function (value, element, params) {
    var valid = false;

    // your validation logic goes here
    // NB element will be undefined as the validator is not driven by an element

    return valid;
});

jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("myvalidationrule", function (options) {
    options.rules["myvalidationrule"] = options.params;
    options.message["myvalidationrule"] = options.message;
});
```

I really hope this makes sense... :S

Comment: The behavior I'm seeing is that `GetClientValidationRules` is never called while the form does not include an input element for `x.SomeProperty` I can't see anything here which I'm not already doing

Comment: Are you sure? This works exactly as I've posted it without the need to render an element, hidden or otherwise. Are you sure you have an implementation of a `ModelClientValidationRule` that you are returning from the `GetClientValidationRules` method in the `ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable`? All I can see is an empty `List` being returned in the sample you have pasted.

Comment: sorry should have read more carefully... I wouldn't know why the method seems to not get called. However, what I do know is that it does work as long as you make sure you have all the component parts I've pasted above. I'm not the first one to have done this and definitely not the last, i.e. this is not an uncommon scenario and therefore catered for.